# Splitting a name into first, middle and last name using Python

Tags: python

So i am basically asking that i have a name and i need to split it into three parts and store it into three different variables using Python.

For example:

Name= "John Wayne Smith"

Then the desired output should be:

First name= John

Middle Name= Wayne

Last name = Smith

Additionally I want to put a check that if for some person middle name is not there then it should be blank.

Comment: Variable names with spaces are not possible in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use split function to make the list which has the names
The first one is the first name second is your last name if names length equals to 2

```
names =Name.split()
if len(names) ==2 :
 print("there is no middle name")
 first_name = names[0]
 last_name = names[1]
 print(f" first name - {first_name}\n  middle name -  last name - {last_name}")
elif len(names) == 3:
 print("there is  middle name")
 first_name = names[0]
 middle_name = names[1]
 last_name = names[2]
 print(f" first name - {first_name}\n middle name - {middle_name} \nlast name - {last_name}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution... Perfect for my scenario...

Comment: please consider upvoting,If my answer is useful

Answer (score 4):

The library **nameparse** is the perfect solution for your question. You can install it by

> pip install nameparser

In your code, import this library as:

```
from nameparser import HumanName

name = "John Wayne Smith"
name_parts = HumanName(name)
name_parts.title
name_parts.first
name_parts.middle
name_parts.last
name_parts.suffix
name_parts.nickname
name_parts.surnames  # (middle + last)
name_parts.initials  # (first initial of each name part)
```

Comment: This worked really well. 

Note that if you're doing this on a Pandas series, you can use it as follows for example to get just the first name:

`from nameparser import HumanName` , 
`from operator import attrgetter` ,
`df['first_name'] = df.full_name.apply(HumanName).apply(attrgetter('first'))`

Comment: @Blewis you're right. That's good approach in case of `pandas` .

Answer (score 1):

We can use following regular expression:

```
(?P<First>\S+)\s(?:(?P<Middle>\S*)\s)?(?P<Last>\S+)$
```

Which looks for a first and last name, and optionally a middle name.

---

**Example**

```
import re

s = "John Wayne Smith"
s2 = "John Smith"

p = re.compile(r"(?P<First>\S+)\s(?:(?P<Middle>\S*)\s)?(?P<Last>\S+)$")
```

```
p.match(s).groupdict()
# {'First': 'John', 'Middle': 'Wayne', 'Last': 'Smith'}

p.match(s2).groupdict()
# {'First': 'John', 'Middle': None, 'Last': 'Smith'}
```

Please note that `match` will match the entire string from start to end. Please make sure to clean and validate your inputs beforehand, as regular expressions are somewhat brittle to inputs they don't expect.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a feature called "unpacking" which allows you to destructure objects from a list. The list in question is from calling the `split` method on the string. It takes a string to split with. To unpack, you must have a declaration of the form `[a, b, c] = list` where a, b and c are objects you wish to unpack (in order). So your code is

```
[first, middle, last] = 'John Wayne Smith'.split(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split` and `len` check on the result:

```py
name = "John Wayne Smith"
parts = name.split(maxsplit=3)
if len(parts) == 3:
    first, middle, last = parts
else:
    first = parts[0]
    middle = ""
    last = parts[-1]
print([first, middle, last])
```

Comment: Add context to increase quality of answer. It avoids flagging by bots or trigger user down-vote behavior. EoR.